# proxy html code via php

Tags: javascript, php, dom

I'm trying to proxy html code (including js and all other resources) in my website.
So I'm creating an iframe and through my proxy I'm making the request for the html code and injecting it into the iframe, and in the php code I'm also parsing the content and replacing all urls to my proxy.
And its good in most cases but when there is content that changes via javascript, let's say like "img src" I can't handle this.

So my question is if there is a way to wrap the html code in javascript so that any request to external resource will be automatically proxided?

Comment: You would need to alter the JavaScript code. Other than this I cannot imagine how to achieve this. I think a generic approach is not possible.

Comment: maybe i can attach some JS to the code that i retrieved so every resource that will be loaded (like src) will be handled by my function so i can proxy it?